# Android softinput mode

Tags: android

I have a form that looks like this:

[image: requestdemo]

And when the user opens the keyboard it looks like:

[image]

I want the keyboard to push up the form as it is doing, but I want it to ignore the terms of service part at the bottom, ie. I want that to stay below the keyboard. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you share your XML layout file ?

Answer (score 0):

Set OnFocusChangeListener on textview/edittext and implement onFocusChange

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) { 
    if(hasFocus){ 
        termslayout.setVisibility(View.Invisible)
     } 
    if(!hasFocus){
        termslayout.setVisibility(View.visible)
    }
}
```

**Edit:** set `android:isScrollContainer="false"` to your terms layout. And if it still does not work, set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your android manifest.

Comment: That won't work as the edit text could have focus but the user has closed the keyboard and the terms will not show.

Answer (score 0):

play with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in manifest for your activity. try using each of combination below

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml goto activity and this line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this for your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible"></activity>
```

Play around with the options, see what works for you.